# How to change pg_hba.conf file with a2-hosting/cPanel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, cpanel

I am trying to connect node.js with a postgres-db at a2-Hosting, but I always get the postgres errorcode: *2800*.

Not sure what the problem is but most people suggest to change everything from ident to md5 in the pg_hba.conf.

Sadly I am not able to find it because a2 does not show any database related folders.

How can I edit `pg_hba.conf` via cPanel?